# Label in javafx does not change

Tags: javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

This is the code for controller

```
package Views;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;

public class menuController {

    @FXML
    private Label eNameLabel;
    @FXML
    private Button productListButton;
    @FXML
    private Button employeeListButton;
    @FXML
    private Button ingredientListButton;
    @FXML
    private Button addProductButton;
    @FXML
    private Button addIngreidentButton;
    @FXML
    private Button addEmployeeButton;
    @FXML
    private Button LogOutButton;
    @FXML
    private Label clockLabel;



    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        clock();
    }

    public void clock(){
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    //  int day= cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    //  int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    //  int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        Date currentDate = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

    //  int second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    //  int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    //  int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);

        this.clockLabel.setText(dateFormat.format(currentDate));
    }
}
```

My label is not changed when I start my program.
I have checked that the label id is given in the scene-builder and everything is connected to its controller or variable.

This is the fxml file that is connected to the controller.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="764.0" prefWidth="901.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Views.menuController">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane layoutY="2.0" prefHeight="764.0" prefWidth="951.0">
         <children>
            <HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="746.0" spacing="20.0">
               <children>
                  <Label lineSpacing="10.0" text="Welcom!">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="55.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Label fx:id="eNameLabel" lineSpacing="10.0" prefHeight="81.0" prefWidth="244.0" text="Label">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="55.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
               </children>
            </HBox>
            <Button fx:id="LogOutButton" layoutX="768.0" layoutY="704.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#logOutButtonPushed" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="176.0" text="Log Out" />
            <Button fx:id="employeeListButton" layoutX="74.0" layoutY="301.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="81.0" prefWidth="215.0" text="Employee List" />
            <Button fx:id="productListButton" layoutX="368.0" layoutY="301.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="81.0" prefWidth="215.0" text="Products List" />
            <Button fx:id="ingredientListButton" layoutX="661.0" layoutY="301.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="81.0" prefWidth="215.0" text="Ingredients List" />
            <Label fx:id="clockLabel" layoutX="74.0" layoutY="710.0" text="Clock" />
            <Button fx:id="addEmployeeButton" layoutX="74.0" layoutY="439.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="81.0" prefWidth="215.0" text="Add Employee" />
            <Button fx:id="addProductButton" layoutX="368.0" layoutY="439.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="81.0" prefWidth="215.0" text="Add Products" />
            <Button fx:id="addIngreidentButton" layoutX="661.0" layoutY="439.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="81.0" prefWidth="215.0" text="Add Ingredients" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

When I run the program, the clockLabel stays 'clock' and does not change. 
It also does not give me any error.
When I put clock(); in a constructor I made later, it gave me a nullPointerException error at this.clockLabel.setText(dateFormat.format(currentDate));

I tried getting rid of this in  this.clockLabel.setText(dateFormat.format(currentDate)); but it didnt work either.

Comment: The code you posted does not compile. What is class `SceneChanger`? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The `Scenechanger` part has no influence on the problem i am having.It can be ignored as it only enables a button to direct user to another page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `initialize` method taking parameters is only considered, if it's overriding the method from `Initializable`. In your case the controller class does not implement `Initializable`, so `FXMLLoader` only looks for an `initialize()` method. Either remove the parameters of the method or add `implements Initializable` to the class.

As for the constructor resulting in a NPE: the injection of the fields happens after the constructor completes in the lifecycle of the controller:

1. `FXMLLoader.load` is entered
2. Parsing the fxml the loader encounters the `fx:controller` attribute and uses reflection to create a instance of the controller.
3. The fields are injected based on their `fx:id`s
4. The `FXMLLoader.load` returns.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Fabian's answer - you can also use the @FXML annotation to make sure the correct method is used:

```
@FXML
private void initialize() {
    ...
}
```